# Splitting String from Settings

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read out the contents off a Setting inside my Application. Below is the code i'm having troubles with:

```
private bool checkGrid()
{
    string playlists = Spotify_Extender.Properties.Settings.Default.Playlists;

    MessageBox.Show(playlists);

    string[] split1;

    if (playlists.Contains(";"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Multiple Links");
        split1 = playlists.Split(';');
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("One Link");
        split1 = new string[1];
        split1[0] = playlists;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Array Length: " + split1.Length);

    int lines = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < split1.Length; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Check #" + i + " - " + split1[i] + " - Length: " + split1[i].Length);
        if (split1[i].Length >= 22)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(i + " - " + split1[1]);
            lines++;
        }
    }

    int rows = this.playlistGrid.Rows.Count;

    MessageBox.Show(lines + "");

    if (rows == lines)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

The code should be easy to understand and it should work as far as i am aware, but it doesn't. I entered this in my Setting:

[image]

If i run the program now, my first MessageBox prints out exactly what i entered, the second one prints out "One Link" and the third prints "Array Length: 1". Now we get to the part i'm having troubles with. The next Message is this:

[image]

So the length of the text is 22 as displayed in the MessageBox, but down below this statement isn't true:

```
if (split1[i].Length >= 22)
```

I'm really confused by this and it also does this when i check this:

```
if (split1[i] != "")
```

Any help is appreciated, because i don't know what to do, since my code should be fine. Thanks for your time!

Comment: What you mean "this statement isn't true"? Any error message or it just skip the statement in `if`? Moreover, please help to check `MessageBox.Show(i + " - " + split1[1]);` is typo or you really want to print the `split1[` **1** `]`?

Comment: ohh you are right it should be split1[i], thanks, but this doesn't change sthe fact that the if statement is skipped

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line you're having trouble with, run the code and when you think the line is not behaving as expected, what is the ACTUAL value of `split1[i]`? This should be the first thing you do.

Comment: Also I suggest to clear the solution/project, because I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: @MattJones the value of split1[i] is printed out in a msgbox above and shouldnt change till it gets to the if statement

Comment: I didn't ask what was printed out in the message box - I said that you should be debugging your application. It's right there in code - set a breakpoint and actually see what the value is at run time. I can't reproduce your error either.

Comment: @Prisoner thanks you actually fixed the problem ^^ The 1 couldn't be anything since it's not assigned...

Answer (score -1):

You should have `split[i]` and not `split[1]`

Comment: This is already been said in comments and the OP acknowledged the typo but it doesn't explain the problem stated in the question.